# nearSphere needs a map operator

Tags: android, parse-platform, geopoints

//Rahees is  class in Parse.com for android from where I want to get the list of nearest location from geopoint g.Rahees class has column name "Locations".

I want to get the list of nearest geopoints from g by comparing it with the geopoints listed in Location column of Rahees class

//******************Rahees Class************************//

```
@ParseClassName("Rahees")
public class Rahees extends ParseObject {

   public  Rahees()
    {
        super();
    }


    public String getDisplayName() {
        return getString("displayName");
    }
    public void setDisplayName(String value) {

        put("displayName", value);
    }
    public static ParseQuery<Rahees> getQuery() {
        return ParseQuery.getQuery(Rahees.class);
    }

}
```

//************Main Activity*******************************//

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ParseGeoPoint g;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ParseUser cuser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

        Rahees haila = new Rahees();

        haila.setDisplayName("Rahim");

    }


   //button for Logging out of system
    public void logout(View view)
    {
        ParseUser.logOut();
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SignUp_Login.class);
        startActivity(intent);


    }

//Button for going to Map Masti class, it is this button which triggers to compare the geopoint g with the geopoints in the server


    public void go_to_maps(View view)
    {

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Map_Masti.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

//****************************MapMasti Class*****************************//

```
public class Map_Masti extends FragmentActivity  {
    ParseGeoPoint g;
    private TextView textView;
    private SupportMapFragment mapFragment;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map_masti);

        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
        mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment);

//Query to get the geopoint g from server 

        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
        query.getInBackground("ccm3xKMmr4", new GetCallback<ParseUser>() {
            public void done(ParseUser object, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    g = (ParseGeoPoint) object.get("user_Location");
                    Log.d("mohit", g + "");

                } else {
                    // something went wrong
                    Log.d("mohit", e + " ");
                }
            }
        });
```

//query to compare which geopoints in the object "Rahees"  with column "Locations" are near to geopoing "g"

```
 ParseQuery<Rahees> mapQuery1 = Rahees.getQuery();
        mapQuery1.whereWithinKilometers("Locations", g, 6000);
        mapQuery1.setLimit(3);
        mapQuery1.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Rahees>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<Rahees> objects, ParseException e) {
                // Handle the results
                if (e == null) {//****this is where the exception error comes, it doesn't goes inside if statement**** 
                    for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
                        Log.d("mohit", "2" + objects.get(i).get("Locations"));

                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d("mohit", "" + e);
                }
            }
        });

}
}
```

Below is the error I am getting , from the else part

01-10 12:27:38.655 4348-4348/? D/error: com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: $nearSphere needs a map operator

I am able to retrive value of g from Parse,output of Log for g is :
ParseGeoPoint[40.000000,30.000000]

Please help

Comment: please provide declaration of `g` variable

Comment: Please check the edited question @gio.Thanks

Comment: Please provide full code of class to see relations between fields and calss

Comment: @gio please check the upated code

Comment: I did not see at update where is your problem code called?

Comment: I want to see order of those calls

Comment: Not sure if got you correct
1)There is button called go_to_Maps in the main activity from where the intent passes to Map Masti class
2)Inside MapMasti's oncreate there are two queries
a)First to get the geopoint from the User object of Parse server, which will fetch us g value (which I am getting correctly method)
b)Second is to compare that g with the gepoints residing in "Location " column of "Rahees" and give the nearest geopoints

Not sure if I answered your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do second query only after will get result of first one, because `g` is `null` until will be initialized by callback.

Update:

```
public class Map_Masti extends FragmentActivity {
    ParseGeoPoint g;
    private SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
    private TextView textView;

    private void getG() {
        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
        query.getInBackground("ccm3xKMmr4", new GetCallback<ParseUser>() {
            public void done(ParseUser object, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    g = (ParseGeoPoint) object.get("user_Location");
                    Log.d("mohit", g + "");
                    getLocations();

                } else {
                    // something went wrong
                    Log.d("mohit", e + " ");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void getLocations() {
        ParseQuery<Rahees> mapQuery1 = Rahees.getQuery();
        mapQuery1.whereWithinKilometers("Locations", g, 6000);
        mapQuery1.setLimit(3);
        mapQuery1.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Rahees>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<Rahees> objects, ParseException e) {
                // Handle the results
                if (e == null) {//****this is where the exception error comes, it doesn't goes inside if statement****
                    for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
                        Log.d("mohit", "2" + objects.get(i).get("Locations"));

                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d("mohit", "" + e);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map_masti);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment);
        getG();
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay.But as seen I have Log command in the first query  , where g value is successfully retrieved .This is well before the next query is called.Could you write  the change in the code suggested.

Comment: add if(null == g) return; before second query and see result

Comment: Yes gio, you are right, I placed if(null == g) after first query yet g was null.So could you please tell me how should I modify code to check if g value has been retrieved and only then I use the second query

Comment: Thanks a lot gio. It would be great if could explain the logic for right placement of the ==> getLocations(); method.I suppose it should  be inside the public void done method ?

Comment: it makes sense only when there is no error, that's why I put it under `if(e==null)` condition

Comment: Got it...Thanks again gio!!